# How to fix the error p: Geometry (wkid: 102723) cannot be converted to spatial reference of the map (wkid: 102100)

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

im getting this error in the console when I tried to add a dynamic layer

```
**p: Geometry (wkid: 102723) cannot be converted to spatial reference of the map (wkid: 102100)**

function mapDirective($rootScope,MapService) {
    function addLayers(map){
        var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(config.gisServer, {});
        map.addLayer(layer);
        MapService.setData('layer',layer);
    }
    return {
        template: require('./mapDirective.html'),
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            onmapready: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                zoom: 5,
                basemap: "topo",
                sliderPosition: "bottom-left",
                extent: new Extent({
                    xmin:1381092.7817073173,
                    ymin:-428571.11493902426,
                    xmax:1406749.947560976,ymax:443420.3850609755,
                    spatialReference:{wkid:102723}})
            });
            map.on("load",function(){
                MapService.setData('map',map);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('map-ready',map);
            });
            addLayers(map);
        }
    };
}
```

I tried to use same extent and spatial reference of dynamic layer when creating basemap , And my dynamic layer is not adding in the map

Comment: can you give us basemap url?

Comment: verify spatialReference of map and ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer are same on not.